# ¿Cómo se dice: "Me rompí el brazo" o "me quebré el brazo"; "me rompí la pierna" o "me quebré la pierna"?

Tags: gramática

Normalmente relacionamos el quebrar con algo duro y rígido y el romper con algo blando, lo que me hace pensar que

> Me rompí el brazo

suena correcto. Pero a lo que nos referimos es al hueso, y no al brazo en si, entonces no debería ser:

> Me quebré el brazo?

Sin embargo esto suena semánticamente incorrecto debido a que el brazo es algo blando y no rígido.

Tratando de aplicar la misma regla con *pierna*

> Me quebré la pierna

Suele ser más popular y común que decir

> Me rompí la pierna

¿Cuál debería ser la forma correcta para expresar esto, para que sea gramatical y semánticamente correcto?

Comment: En el contexto del cuerpo humano, el hueso sí es rígido, en comparación con otros tejidos del cuerpo.  Quizás no es tan rígido como el acero, pero hay que tener en cuenta el contexto.  Creo que por eso se usa frecuentemente *quebrar*.

Comment: @aparente001 a lo que me refiero es que semanticamente hablando del brazo no forma parte de cuerpos rígidos, a pesar de que en el contexto podamos entender que se trata del hueso, la frase en esencia posee un fallo semantico.

Comment: Habías puesto "esto suena semánticamente incorrecto debido a que el brazo es algo blando y no rígido."  Pero el brazo no es como espagueti.  Es cierto que contiene tejidos elásticos y también hay células que se bañan en líquido (sangre, etc.).  Pero también contiene huesos, que son duros y rígidos.  No tan duros y rígidos como el acero, pero  sí, bastante duros y rígidos. De hecho DRAE define *hueso*: "Cada una de las piezas duras que forman el esqueleto de los vertebrados."

Comment: Al menos yo no relaciono *quebrar* con lo rígido y *romper* con lo blando, no de esa manera.

Comment: puedes quebrar una hoja de papel?

Comment: ¿Sería correcto decir “se me rompió el brazo” y “se me quebró la pierna”, al menos que no sea un accidente inesperado? https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verbs/accidental-reflexive/

Comment: @Traveller el uso del reflexivo es correcto en el español, pero son utilizados cuando suceden sin que te des cuenta o sin provocarlo.

Answer (score 3):

En el DLE, [**romper**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WfKlsVn) tiene la acepción

> 2. tr. **Quebrar** o hacer pedazos algo. U. t. c. prnl.

y [**quebrar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UlGmeOB) tiene la acepción

> 1. tr. **Romper**, separar con violencia.

Por tanto creo que cualquiera de las opciones que indicas es válida.

Comment: Perdón, @rotten, no sabía cómo avisarte de este post de Meta que podría ser de interés para tí, así que te hago un ping aquí: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2944/9385